# OData client with support for Navigation properties

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

Is there any OData clients with reporting capabilities that can handle navigation properties? We tested Pebble Reports and I really like it but it doesnt include the navigation properties so I am not able to drill down from one entity set to another.

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to get any client to drill down? I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The closest one I have found is the [Odata Explorer](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/odataexplorer/default.html). There is no reporting capabilities with it though. It takes your links and creates a column for them in the table. The value in each row is the link's title. When clicked it opens up another data set that link returned. So it's a way to follow your links. There is no way to really expand any of the links in a single call.

It seems you can't eat your cake, just have it - reporting with limited abilities to dig into the data or the ability to see and dig into the data but not be able to report on it. Let me know if you find anything better, I'm looking for a good combination as well. The software is really playing catch-up to the standard it seems.

Comment: I sent an email to Pebble and asked if Pebble reports will get support for navigation properties. They said that they plan to implement it this summer.